# EXTJS Dataview selection wont display

Tags: css, extjs, extjs6-modern

I'm trying to build a dataview to display some pictures. These pictures I want to select (should be highlighted) and then interact with them (delete e.g.)

```
xtype: 'dataview',
        id:'fotodataview',
        scrollable: true,
        inline: true,
        mode: 'MULTI',           
        cls:'dataview-inline',
        itemTpl: '<div class="img" style="background-image:url({image}); "> </div><div class="name">{name}<br/>{date}</div>',          
        store: dataViewStore,
        listeners:{
            //itemtap:'onItemTap'
        }
```

What do I have to add to have a highlighted item? Do I have the toggle the selection on my own when tapping a item?  Do I have to add a cls to simulate a selection? (e.g. like list?)

/e I'm developing a modern app only!

Comment: Ok got it.  Problem was the amount of tap functions in dataview.  used itemtap which wont select even if I used the select mehtod. changed to select only event . seems like I deselected my records every time..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own css to achieve this:

```
.dataview-inline .x-item-selected
{
//your selection style
}
```

**OR**

you can created your your select class & mention it in `selectedCls` property:

```
selectedCls:'<yourSelectClass>'  // property in your dataview
.<yourSelectClass>{             // css class
//your selection style
}
```

Comment: When using selectAll() all my views get selected ,except the one I clicked..the method select and selectrange wont select anything at all. Select event gets fired every time. /ot how can I use enter in this editbox. ?

Comment: `code` onSelect:function( me, record, eOpts ){
        console.log("on select");
        
        var dataview = Ext.getCmp('fotodataview');
       

        var bool = dataview.isSelected(record);
        console.log(bool);


        var count = dataview.getSelectionCount();
        console.log("Amount of records selcted: " + count);

        var mode = dataview.getMode();
        console.log("Selction Mode is: " + mode);
        
    } `code` thats the function in controller nothing fancy. VIew adds select() to listeners.

Comment: `code`.dataview-inline .x-item-selected{
    background-color: #00B8CE;
    opacity: 0.3;    
} `code`